# Can I add click event on disabled dates in owl date time picker?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm trying to put a click event on owl-date-time-picker, Is it possible?

[owl-date-time-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnoqO.png)

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    [owlDateTime]="datePicker"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    class="form-control"
    [ngClass]="{ invalid: invalid }"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [max]="maxDate"
    [min]="minDate"
    [selectMode]="selectMode"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="onDateChanged()"
    [owlDateTimeFilter]="filter"
  />
  <button [owlDateTimeTrigger]="datePicker" [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="{ invalid: invalid }"
          class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa-calendar"></i>
  </button>
  <owl-date-time #datePicker [pickerMode]="pickerMode" [pickerType]="pickerType"></owl-date-time>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure. You can add. A quick solution would be to add your date picker inside a div with `position: relative` and add one empty div adjacent to your datepicker like this:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div id="datePickerDiv" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;opacity:0">something here...</div>
// Your date picker here
</div>
```

you can then write a simple JS click event for this div which would be at same place as the datepicker but with opacity 0.

```
document.querySelector('#datePickerDiv').onclick = function () {
    
 alert('Disabled datepicker is clicked!');
}
```

Try it out...!!!

Comment: I want to add click event on disabled dates.